# Split data by months and years in R

Tags: r

I need to split my long data by years and by month. My data is in "dat" format. And sample data is below. Date is in Month/Day/Year

```
                   Date X. Value
 1/1/2017 12:02:00 AM  -   2.0
 1/1/2017 12:03:00 AM  -   1.0
 1/2/2017 12:04:00 AM  -   3.5
 1/2/2017 12:05:00 AM  -   0.0
 1/3/2018 12:06:00 AM  -   0.0
 1/3/2018 12:07:00 AM  -   5.0
 2/1/2018 12:08:00 AM  -   1.0
 2/1/2018 12:09:00 AM  -   2.2
 2/1/2018 12:10:00 AM  -   0.0
 2/2/2018 12:11:00 AM  -   3.0
 2/2/2018 12:12:00 AM  -   0.0
```

Structure is here.

```
        data<-structure(list(Date = structure(1:11, .Label = c("1/1/2017 12:02:00 AM", 
"1/1/2017 12:03:00 AM", "1/2/2017 12:04:00 AM", "1/2/2017 12:05:00 AM", 
"1/3/2018 12:06:00 AM", "1/3/2018 12:07:00 AM", "2/1/2018 12:08:00 AM", 
"2/1/2018 12:09:00 AM", "2/1/2018 12:10:00 AM", "2/2/2018 12:11:00 AM", 
"2/2/2018 12:12:00 AM"), class = "factor"), X. = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "-", class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(2, 1, 3.5, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2.2, 0, 3, 0)), .Names = c("Date", 
"X.", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

And finally, I want to get these;

```
[1]
     1/1/2017 12:02:00 AM  -   2.0
     1/1/2017 12:03:00 AM  -   1.0
     1/2/2017 12:04:00 AM  -   3.5
     1/2/2017 12:05:00 AM  -   0.0

[2]
     1/3/2018 12:06:00 AM  -   0.0
     1/3/2018 12:07:00 AM  -   5.0

[3]
     2/1/2018 12:08:00 AM  -   1.0
     2/1/2018 12:09:00 AM  -   2.2
     2/1/2018 12:10:00 AM  -   0.0
     2/2/2018 12:11:00 AM  -   3.0
     2/2/2018 12:12:00 AM  -   0.0
```

Comment: Are you splitting by year (or how the month are divided)? Why Jan and Feb 2017 (and 2018) are in the same group?

Comment: @s_t Actually they are not in same group. The format is M/D/Y. so for [1], there are only January 2017 values. for [2]; there are only January 2018, and for 3; February 2018

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this might work for your purpose

```
split(data, with(data,gsub("(\\d+)/\\d+/(\\d+).*","\\1/\\2",Date)))
```

yielding

```
$`1/2017`
                  Date X. Value
1 1/1/2017 12:02:00 AM  -   2.0
2 1/1/2017 12:03:00 AM  -   1.0
3 1/2/2017 12:04:00 AM  -   3.5
4 1/2/2017 12:05:00 AM  -   0.0

$`1/2018`
                  Date X. Value
5 1/3/2018 12:06:00 AM  -     0
6 1/3/2018 12:07:00 AM  -     5

$`2/2018`
                   Date X. Value
7  2/1/2018 12:08:00 AM  -   1.0
8  2/1/2018 12:09:00 AM  -   2.2
9  2/1/2018 12:10:00 AM  -   0.0
10 2/2/2018 12:11:00 AM  -   3.0
11 2/2/2018 12:12:00 AM  -   0.0
```

Comment: Is it possible to obtain only "value" columns? For example for '1/2017' section, I want to see only values ,instead of 'date, X. and value'

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi then you can try `split(data[-(1:2)], with(data,gsub("(\\d+)/\\d+/(\\d+).*","\\1/\\2",Date)))`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution in base R using `split`:

```
split(data, format(as.Date(data$Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"), format = "%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: It seems the data are in mdy hms format, so your result does not fit with OP request (maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 2):

If adding another column to your dataset doesn't bother you, you could `group_split` on a new column `month`:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(yearMonth = paste0(lubridate::year(lubridate::dmy_hms(Date)), lubridate::month(lubridate::dmy_hms(Date))) %>% 
  group_split(yearMonth)
```

if needed, this column could be removed afterwards...

```
data %>% 
  mutate(yearMonth = paste0(lubridate::year(lubridate::dmy_hms(Date)), lubridate::month(lubridate::dmy_hms(Date))) %>% 
  lapply(., function(df) df %>% select(-yearMonth))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this, you convert as date `data$Date` with `lubridate::mdy_hms()`, then you fetch the year and the month, last you `split()` with the combinations of year and month:

```
library(lubridate)
split( data, f = paste(month(mdy_hms(data$Date)),year(mdy_hms(data$Date)),sep="/" ))

$`1/2017`
                  Date X. Value
1 1/1/2017 12:02:00 AM  -   2.0
2 1/1/2017 12:03:00 AM  -   1.0
3 1/2/2017 12:04:00 AM  -   3.5
4 1/2/2017 12:05:00 AM  -   0.0

$`1/2018`
                  Date X. Value
5 1/3/2018 12:06:00 AM  -     0
6 1/3/2018 12:07:00 AM  -     5

$`2/2018`
                   Date X. Value
7  2/1/2018 12:08:00 AM  -   1.0
8  2/1/2018 12:09:00 AM  -   2.2
9  2/1/2018 12:10:00 AM  -   0.0
10 2/2/2018 12:11:00 AM  -   3.0
11 2/2/2018 12:12:00 AM  -   0.0
```

In case you prefere a base R solution:

```
split( data, f = paste(
  format(as.Date(data$Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"), format = "%m")
  ,format(as.Date(data$Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"), format = "%Y")
  ,sep="/" ))
```